# c# how to convert code into a generic version?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am trying to write this code in a more generic fashion:Is it possible that based on T i can use the right entityframework entity? So for example if I would use :

```
public IQueryable<T> GetCount(string filterExpression)
{
   //return db.Persons.Where("it." + filterExpression);
   return db. ? .Where("it." + filterExpression); // depending on type T
}
```

UPDATE

so now I did this:

```
  public int GetCount<T>(string filter)
        where T : class
        {
            NortwindEntities db = new NortwindEntities();
            return db.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(filter).Count();
        }
```

error:

```
Error   2   The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'MyBase<T>.GetCount<T>(string)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'MyBase<T>.GetCount<T>(string)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use the `IEnumerable<TSource>.Count<TSource>(Func<TSource,bool> predicate)` extension method from Linq ?

Comment: Your error is because both you class and your method are parametrized with the same `T` type, if you want a different type for the method with specific constraints like `where T : class`, you need to pick another generic class Name such as `TSource`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want a queryable of `T`? (the name of your method is `GetCount`.)

You can do this to get a `IQueryable<T>` from your `DbContext`.

```
public IQueryable<T> GetCount<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    where T : class
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();
    return db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
}

IQueryable<Person> result = GetCount<Person>(x => x.Id == 1);
```

I suggest to use the name `Where` as your method name.

```
public IQueryable<T> Where<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    where T : class
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();
    return db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
}

IQueryable<Person> result = Where<Person>(x => x.Id == 1);
```

### Update

Decorate the method with `where T : class` if you get the following exception.

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method ?

### Update 2

Seems that you really only want the count.

```
public int GetCount<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    where T : class
{
    MyContext db = new MyContext();
    return db.Set<T>().Where(predicate).Count();
}

int count = GetCount<Person>(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Comment: GetCount should be GetCount<T>

Comment: @dknaack I am using an ObjectContext , there is no .Set?

Comment: Glad to help! Have a nice day and consider to accept, but only if this helps.

Comment: when I do  int ISOABServiceBase<T>.GetCount<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) 
        {
            PermissionsSOABEntities db = new PermissionsSOABEntities();
                return db.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(predicate).Count();
        }
I get an error: Error 3 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method ?

Comment: @HanssieTeeuwen See my comment on the question. If you want the `T` parameter from your class to be the same as for your method, just define the method as `public int GetCount(Func<T, bool> predicate) {...}`. If you want it to be (potentialy) different type from `T` just rename it and declare the method as `public int GetCount<TSource>(Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource:class`